# Can a Yosemite extension enable itself without the user turning it on?

Tags: finder, macos

I'm working on Yosemite Finder sync extension, and I need to know if I'm able to enable it by myself without forcing users to turn it on.

I've noticed that on start it writes message into log:

```
PM com.apple.preferences.extensions.remoteservice[2241]: ### com.MyHome.FinderExtension setting enabled:1
```

Can I turn it on manually somehow?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you found a solution ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`pluginkit -e use -i <com.XXX.plugin_bundle_id>` installs the extension!

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible how I think you wish it would be: through Objective-C code within your app. This would be a security risk if this would be permitted. In a similar fashion to enabling accessibility options for an app, the app itself is not able to set this. Furthermore, through GUI scripting, accessibility must be enabled for your app anyway, which is more hassle than it is worth for the end user.

Comment: But dropbox does it. If you enable or disable finder integration, dropbox enables and disables their finder extension.